# Python Regex to capture whats in between

Tags: python, regex

i'm trying to write a regex which will get the following:

1. Given a string
2. Get whats in-between Dim and ( or : or space or ,
3. If the above is not occurred, return nothing

So far i have written the below which works kinda well except that i'm not sure how to get it to remove "(" or ":" or ","

```
def get_name(line):
subStr = re.findall(r'Dim(.+)As|$', line)[0]
return subStr
```

Example

```
txt = "Dim MyLine() As"
subStr = re.findall(r'Dim(.+)As|$', txt)[0]
#Prints MyLine(), But I want it to print MyLine
```

Same for the cases
"Dim MyLine:"
"Dim MyLine As"
"Dim MyLine,"
"Dim MyLine() As"

I Want to get only "MyLine" from all the above cases, and only if they occur.

Comment: Please inclue example/sample text input/output so we can help further.

Comment: @Jab Sorry I updated the Original Post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by return nothing, so I will assume you want to return `None`.

```py
>>> import re
>>>
>>>
>>> def get_name(line):
...     try:
...         return re.findall(r'Dim\s*(.+?)([(: ,]|$)', line)[0][0]
...     except IndexError:
...         return None
...
>>> get_name('Dim MyLine() As')
'MyLine'
```

If there is no match, the `findall` returns an empty list, so if we want to access the first element, that will raise `IndexError`, we catch that, and return `None`.

Regex: `Dim\s*(.+?)[(: ,]`

- Dim
- `\s*`: any number of whitespace character
- `(`: first group starts
- `.+?`: At least one time any character (non-greedy matching)
- `)`: first group ends
- `[(: ,]`: One of these characters: `(: ,`

Comment: How to modify the expression here to return "MyLine" in the case of "Dim MyLine As"

Comment: I Added "|[As]" after ",]" and it seem to be working, however, I do not want it to get other A's or s's and only excatly "As" i will need to debug this case

Comment: No need to modify anything. It returns `MyLine` in case of all of your example inputs.

Comment: You're welcome. :) And please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Can you please help me add one more case if possible which is "Dim MyLine"

Comment: Ok, Adding "\s" after "," worked ... Not sure if there will be any issue with this ?

Comment: I modified my answer to also accept end-of-string as a delimiter.